# warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

Tags: java, compiler-errors, warnings

What does this error mean?

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
```

Is it that the particular piece of code isn't compatible with the Java version?